# Compile error: "Function or interface marked as restricted or the function uses an Automation type not supported by visual basic"

Tags: vb6, dao

I am working on an VB6 application on Windows 7. I have a statement in my project that states:

```
Set Dbse = OpenDatabase(database name)
Set ds1 = Dbse.CreateDynaset("query here")
```

But when I am trying to create an exe for the project, I am getting the below error:

> "Function or interface marked as restricted,or the function uses an
>   autoamtion type not supported in visual basic".

Could you please suggest me what to be done to resolve this compile error.

Comment: @niyou The question that you linked to doesn't actually have anything to do with the issue that the OP is seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Go into `Project -> References`.

Remove all of the references that you have to any DAO items (uncheck all items).

Add a reference to "Microsoft DAO 2.5/3.51 Compatibility Library".

Comment: @user3089876 Out of total curiousity, why are you using technology as old as DAO?